# Increase font size in Eclipse view

Tags: eclipse

I am using a plugin that prints useful info in some grid (see picture below). However, due to the resolution of my laptop (2880x1620) I see nothing - the row height is too small. Is there a way how to increase this row height? I do not want to decrease font size as that would be almost unreadable.

[image]

Comment: did u tried searching your plugin console name in windows-preference-color&fonts

Comment: @NarendraJaggi Well, yes. I can make the font smaller (size 5), and then it fits in the rows. However, the text is so small that I have to have my eyes for inches from the monitor to read it :)